# How can I scroll a text editing View automatically so that cursor stays in the screen?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-webview

I use the Library richeditor (https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) which extends WebView to create a Rich Text Box.

When I type in the RichEditor (at runtime) the cursor goes down as new lines are added as expected.

If you take a text editor in a app like Evernote it automatically scrolls when newlines are added so that the cursor always stays in the screen and shown to the user.

Whereas in my app as I enter new lines the cursor goes down and ultimately go beneath the virtual soft keyboard so that I cannot see the cursor and the new text being typed.

How can I solve this.[image: Notice the light gray color cursor. Here when I add 2 another lines cursor goes behind the black toolbox. I need to scroll the whole screen to avoid that.]